# Как спрятать спрайт в Python Pygame

Tags: python, разработка-игр, pygame, спрайт, hide

Мне нужно чтобы когда `player` касался `game_icon`, `player` исчезал.
Я пытался узнать, но без результата. Помогите пожалуйста.

```
import pygame
import time

# Init

pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()
pygame.display.set_caption("My Game")
pygame.display.set_icon(pygame.image.load("images/game_icon.gif"))
BLACK = (255,255,255)
W, H = 800, 600
x, y = 300, 300
sc = pygame.display.set_mode((W,H))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 60
f1 = pygame.font.Font(None, 50)
HEALTH = 100
health_text = f1.render(f'Health: {HEALTH}', True,(0,0,0)) #rgb

# Lobby Sound
sound = pygame.mixer.music.load("sounds/uwa_so_temperate.mp3")
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)

# Image Load

background_image = pygame.image.load("images/home.png")
item_surf = pygame.image.load('images/game_icon.gif')
item_rect = item_surf.get_rect(center=(x,y))
item_surf.set_colorkey((255, 255, 255))

player_surf = pygame.image.load("images/player.gif")
player_rect = player_surf.get_rect(center=(W//2, H//2))
player_surf.set_colorkey((255, 255, 255))

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit()
    # Render
    health_text = f1.render(f'Health: {HEALTH}', True,(0,0,0))
    sc.fill(BLACK)
    sc.blit(background_image, (0,0))  #154 24
    sc.blit(item_surf, item_rect)
    sc.blit(player_surf, player_rect)
    player_surf.set_colorkey((255, 255, 255))

    sc.blit(health_text, (40,520))
    pygame.display.update()

    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            player_rect.x += -5
            player_surf = pygame.image.load("images/player_left.gif")
            player_surf.set_colorkey((255, 255, 255))
            if player_rect.collidepoint(item_rect.center):
                HEALTH = HEALTH + 1
                player_rect.x += 5
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player_rect.x += 5
                player_surf = pygame.image.load("images/player_right.gif")
                player_surf.set_colorkey((255, 255, 255))
                if player_rect.collidepoint(item_rect.center):
                    HEALTH = HEALTH + 1
                    player_rect.x += -5
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player_rect.y += -5
                player_surf = pygame.image.load("images/player.gif")
                player_surf.set_colorkey((255, 255, 255))
                if player_rect.collidepoint(item_rect.center):
                    HEALTH = HEALTH + 1
                    player_rect.y += 5
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player_rect.y += 5
                player_surf = pygame.image.load("images/player.gif")
                player_surf.set_colorkey((255, 255, 255))
                if player_rect.collidepoint(item_rect.center):
                    HEALTH = HEALTH + 1
                    player_rect.y += -5

        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            player_rect.x += 5
            player_surf = pygame.image.load("images/player_right.gif")
            player_surf.set_colorkey((255, 255, 255))
            if player_rect.collidepoint(item_rect.center):
                HEALTH = HEALTH + 1
                player_rect.x += -5
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player_rect.x += -5
                player_surf = pygame.image.load("images/player_left.gif")
                player_surf.set_colorkey((255, 255, 255))
                if player_rect.collidepoint(item_rect.center):
                    HEALTH = HEALTH + 1
                    player_rect.x += 5
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player_rect.y += -5
                player_surf = pygame.image.load("images/player.gif")
                player_surf.set_colorkey((255, 255, 255))
                if player_rect.collidepoint(item_rect.center):
                    HEALTH = HEALTH + 1
                    player_rect.y += 5
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player_rect.y += 5
                player_surf = pygame.image.load("images/player.gif")
                player_surf.set_colorkey((255, 255, 255))
                if player_rect.collidepoint(item_rect.center):
                    HEALTH = HEALTH + 1
                    player_rect.y += -5

        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            player_rect.y += -5
            player_surf = pygame.image.load("images/player.gif")
            player_surf.set_colorkey((255, 255, 255))
            if player_rect.collidepoint(item_rect.center):
                HEALTH = HEALTH + 1
                player_rect.y += 5
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player_rect.y += 5
                player_surf = pygame.image.load("images/player.gif")
                player_surf.set_colorkey((255, 255, 255))
                if player_rect.collidepoint(item_rect.center):
                    HEALTH = HEALTH + 1
                    player_rect.y += -5
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player_rect.x += 5
                player_surf = pygame.image.load("images/player_right.gif")
                player_surf.set_colorkey((255, 255, 255))
                if player_rect.collidepoint(item_rect.center):
                    HEALTH = HEALTH + 1
                    player_rect.x += -5
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player_rect.x += -5
                player_surf = pygame.image.load("images/player_left.gif")
                player_surf.set_colorkey((255, 255, 255))
                if player_rect.collidepoint(item_rect.center):
                    HEALTH = HEALTH + 1
                    player_rect.x += 5
                                    

        if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            player_rect.y += 5
            player_surf = pygame.image.load("images/player.gif")
            player_surf.set_colorkey((255, 255, 255))
            if player_rect.collidepoint(item_rect.center):
                HEALTH = HEALTH + 1
                player_rect.y += -5
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player_rect.x += -5
                player_surf = pygame.image.load("images/player_left.gif")
                player_surf.set_colorkey((255, 255, 255))
                if player_rect.collidepoint(item_rect.center):
                    HEALTH = HEALTH + 1
                    player_rect.x += 5
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player_rect.x += 5
                player_surf = pygame.image.load("images/player_right.gif")
                player_surf.set_colorkey((255, 255, 255))
                if player_rect.collidepoint(item_rect.center):
                    HEALTH = HEALTH + 1
                    player_rect.x += -5
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player_rect.y += -5
                player_surf = pygame.image.load("images/player.gif")
                player_surf.set_colorkey((255, 255, 255))
                if player_rect.collidepoint(item_rect.center):
                    HEALTH = HEALTH + 1
                    player_rect.y += 5

clock.tick(FPS)
```

Comment: Ну просто переставай его отрисовывать в цикле и все.

Comment: Я знаю что надо перестать отрисовывать

Comment: Как перестать отрисовывать?

Comment: Если через Del то получается ошибка

Comment: Добавь условие коллизии и при его ложном значении отрисовывай, в противном случае ничего неделай и он автоматически перестанет отрисовываться.

Comment: Ура, заработало.

Comment: Спасибо, Глеб. В начале я не додумался до этого